# "Array" showing up as error in empty form fields

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to echo out errors from a form using arrays. i store the errors in an array, then I print_r. But when I omit some fields and submit the for I get the string "Array" showng up as an error.

below is the php code I'm working with...

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
      $error = array();
      if (empty($_POST['request'])) { $error .= "<li>Prayer Request is Empty</li>";}
      if (empty($_POST['phone']))   { $error .= "<li>Please enter a valid phone Number</li>";}
      if (empty($_POST['response'])){ $error .= "<li>Please choose a way to contact you.</li>";}
      ?>
          <div class='Errors' >
          <?php print_r ($error); ?>
          </div>
```

Comment: When you simply convert an array to a string, the result is `Array`. You are doing string concatenation with an array!

Comment: If you meant to add the items to the array, use `$error[] =`. But `print_r` doesn’t really make sense in the context of HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Well what did you expect with `$error = array()`?

Try `$error = "";` instead.

Comment: Needs a bit more explanation.

Comment: i dunno, i think this is pretty clear. if the op doesn't understand the difference between strings and arrays, they should be asking questions about THAT instead.

Comment: For us, of course. But with nearly 100k rep, I'd expect a more *diplomatic* answer.

Comment: There is no real way to answer a question like this without sounding like a smartarse. Hopefully by using the rhetorical question I've pointed out exactly what the problem was with the code-writing reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the .= to [] =

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  $error = array();
  if (empty($_POST['request'])) { $error[] = "<li>Prayer Request is Empty</li>";}
  if (empty($_POST['phone']))   { $error[] = "<li>Please enter a valid phone Number</li>";}
  if (empty($_POST['response'])){ $error[] = "<li>Please choose a way to contact you.</li>";}
?>
<div class='Errors' >
<?php print_r ($error); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess Kolinks would work to, depends on if you want to keep it as an array or a string.